# cakePHP 2.6 FormHelper change template

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

everyone.

I have to change the template of the FormHelper. Not for just 1 or 2 view, for ALL views. And i would like to do this without to have to write hundred of line in every view.

Is it possible to change the FormHelper default template ?
Where the default template is located ?

CakePHP documentation don't say anythings in order to change template of Whole Site, for FormHelper or Paginator, that's a real problem.

I'm **not with CakePHP 3** but only **CakePHP 2.6**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to modify or use their own "bake" template, in order to avoid repetition of writing html and php code.

Here is what documentation say: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html#modify-default-html-produced-by-baked-templates

If you want to modify cake helper, copy from

```
\cakephp\lib\Cake\View\Helper
```

in the `\cakephp\app\View\Helper`

and then make modification.

Here is documentations for creating own helpers 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers

Comment: Thanks for reply


For the bake command, that's ok, i already find this documentation, but bake use the paginator component, and i don't know how to change it's template to, like the FormHelper ?


So to change the FormHelper template, i have to create my own helper ?


No way to do that with a configuration file like for Cake 3 ? 
[Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)
_I know, this is for Cake 3_

Answer (score 0):

Well...the file you are looking for is located in

```
/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php
```

You should search for example for:

```
function input(
```

or

```
function create(
```

that is the "template" you are looking for.
I think the easiest way to change the output is to update your $options array. There you can add classes or labels or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for reply

But i'm not sure this is the template i'm searching for, there is no any 'div' or 'input' in that file.

But if i need, i keep your idea :-)

Comment: I think it is exactly what you are looking for. It is just not working the way you expected ;)

`function input` calls `$this->Html->tag` and this function generates your 'div' or 'input' with the array '$_tags'.

As I said. if you want only to change a few lines, you will have to do it here....if you want to change all your views (probably just once) then write your own helper